# How to compare the gradients of two lines

Tags: r, regression, anova

Im using R but have been told to ask this here as its not really an R problem but a stats one

I have the following dataset called `FeqAndASCATmergeCell`

```
   code freq  CNI
1   asd  577   13
2   gdg  989  477
3   grh  843   23
4   asf   26   56
5   ghq  977  123
6   ver  354  921
7   ngj   13   98
8   qwe  439  535
9   wer  867  636
10  ert  829  654
11  rty  410   34
12  tyu  950    6
13  yui  210   34
14  uio  121  636
15  iop  626 3463
16  aax  850  653
17  afd  767  636
18  vfd  655   46
```

I have plotted these so that the x axis is 'code' and freq and CNI are two straight lines based on their values.

[image]

I would like to compare the gradient of the two lines to see if they are significantly different in R. How can I do this? I tried ANOVA but I get the error

```
error in oneway.test(freq ~ CNI, data = FeqAndASCATmergeCell) : 
  not enough observations
```

Comment: I think this question is on topic since it is really about which test to use. I'm sure it is a duplicate, but can't find the thread I'm thinking of ..